# Doubt about find probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I need help with this exercise:

> The river pollution in the United States is a problem of many years. Consider the events below: 
> $A$ = {The river is polluted} 
> $B$ = {A tested sample water detects pollution} 
> $C$ = {Fishing is allowed}

Assume:

> $P(A) = 0.3$ 
> $P(B|A) = 0.75$ 
> $P(B|A^c) = 0.20$ 
> $P(C|A\cap B) = 0.20$ 
> $P(C|A^c \cap B) = 0.15$ 
> $P(C|A \cap B^c) = 0.80$ 
> $P(C|A^c \cap B^c) = 0.90$

(a) Determine $P(A \cap B \cap C)$. 
(b) Determine $P(B^c \cap C)$. 
(c) Determine $P(C)$. 
(d) Determine the probability of the river be polluted given the fishing is allowed and the tested sample didn't detect pollution.

My Try:

(a) $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(C|A \cap B) \cdot P(A \cap B) \\ P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0.2 * P(B|A) * P(A) \\ P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0.2 * 0.75 * 0.3 = 0.045 = 4.5\%$

(b)I'm stuck at this point because I can't find any algebric manipulation in the given formulas and I don't understand the meaning if I draw the Venn Diagram.

Please, help.

Comment: I will let someone share a more interested answer , but usually these kind of exercices are solved using repetitive **de morgan laws** (complementary version) and formula of probability of union in respect of probability of intersection,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \small P(A) = 0.3, P(A^c) = 0.7$
$ \small P(B^c|A) = 1 - 0.75 = 0.25$
$ \small P(B^c|A^c) = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8$

So for question (b), we find
$ \small P(A \cap B^c) = P (B^c|A) \cdot P(A)$
$ \small P(A^c \cap B^c) = P (B^c|A^c) \cdot P(A^c)$

Now note that,

$ \small P(B^c \cap C) = P(B^c \cap C \cap A) + P(B^c \cap C \cap A^c)$

$ \small  = P(C|A \cap B^c) \cdot P(A \cap B^c) + P(C|A^c \cap B^c) \cdot P(A^c \cap B^c)$

You can find and add $\small P(B \cap C)$ to the above for question $(c)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know this step. I got stuck exactly at this point. $P(B^c∩C)=P(B^c∩C∩A)+P(B^c∩C∩A^c)$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

(a) $$P(A\cap B\cap C)=(0.3)(0.75)(0.2)$$
(b) $$P(B^c\cap C)=(0.3)(1-0.75)(0.8)+(1-0.3)(1-0.2)(0.9)$$
(c) $$P(C)=(0.3)(0.75)(0.2)+(0.3)(1-0.75)(0.8)+(1-0.3)(0.2)(0.15)+(1-0.3)(1-0.2)(0.9)$$
(d) $$P(A|B^c\cap C)=(0.3)(1-0.75)(0.8)\div\text{answer to part (b)}$$